# Equivalent Azure ARM APIs for ComputeManagementClient operations like create, get, swap

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager, service-management

I have to replace the service management API's with Azure ARM and I am finding very difficult to find a proper documentation for the following equivalent Azure ARM API's

1) **ComputeManagementClient.Deployments.Create**
- I found the API to GET deployment by slot with the help of azure resource explorer.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mySubID}/resourceGroups/{myResourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{myCloudService}/slots/Production?api-version=2016-04-01
```

What is PUT/POST request body for the same ?

2) **ComputeManagementClient.Deployments.swap**
  - What is the API to Swap deployment with Production slot ?

3) **ComputeManagementClient.HostedServices.Create**

```
 https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{mySubID}/resourceGroups/{myResourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{myCloudService}/slots/Production?api-version=2016-04-01
```

Will the above API create cloud service ? If so what are the parameters should be in the Request body  ?

Answer (score 2):

To create deployment slot you can adapt this arm template piece (properties would be the body, path would be combination of name + type), refer to [this](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/classicresources.json) for some additional examples:

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
        "name": "slotName",
        "type": "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots",
        "dependsOn": [
            "cloudServiceName"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "deploymentLabel": "[parameters('deploymentLabel')]",
            "packageLink": {
                "Uri": "[parameters('packageLink')]"
            },
            "configurationLink": {
                "Uri": "[parameters('configurationLink')]"
            },
            "deploymentOptions": "[parameters('deploymentOptions')]"
        }
    }
```

Also, your best source of such information is fiddler ;) ( at least that how I got to know it )

Answer (score 2):

For Deployments.Create please refer to 4c74356b41's answer. I test the create cloudservice and swap slot on my side, it works correctly.

> ComputeManagementClient.Deployments.swap - What is the API to Swap deployment with Production slot ?

please have a try to use the following REST API to swap the deployment with Production slot.

```
post https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{cloudservicename}/swap?api-version=2015-06-01
```

[image]

> Will the above API create cloud service ? If so what are the parameters should be in the Request body ?

Yes, we could use the Rest API to create  cloudservice.

```
put https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroupname}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{cloudservicename}?api-version=2016-04-01
```

Body:

```
  {
   "properties": {},
   "location": "eastus" //location
  }
```

[image]

**Note**: please make sure that your subcription supports to create the cloudservice in that location. If it is not supported, we will get the following error.

> The location constraint is not valid